# jira rest api error in creating issue

Tags: php, rest

hi i am getting following error when trying to create an issue in jira using rest api with php.Error(s) creating issue:
      object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'errorMessages' =>
       array (size=0)
        empty
       public 'errors' =>
        object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'summary' => string 'Field 'summary' cannot be set. It is
          not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.' (length=79)
         public 'description' => string 'Field 'description' cannot be
         set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.' (length=83)
         `
i am using the following source code:

```
<?php

 define('JIRA_URL', 'xxxxxxxx');
 define('USERNAME', 'xxxxxxxxx');
 define('PASSWORD', 'xxxxxxxx');

 function post_to($resource, $data) {
 $curlname=CURLOPT_POST;
 $curlvalue=1;  
 $jdata = json_encode($data);
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    $curlname => $curlvalue,
    CURLOPT_URL => JIRA_URL . '/rest/api/latest/' . $resource,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => USERNAME . ':' . PASSWORD,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $jdata,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json'),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
 ));
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return json_decode($result);
 }

 function create_issue($issue) {
 return post_to('issue', $issue);
 }

 $new_issue = array(
 'fields' => array(
    'project' => array('key' => 'xxx'),
    'summary' => 'Test via REST',
    'description' => 'Description of issue goes here.',
    'issuetype' => array('name' => 'Task')
 )
 );

 $result = create_issue($new_issue);
 if (property_exists($result, 'errors')) {
 echo "Error(s) creating issue:\n";
 var_dump($result);
  } else {
 echo "New issue created at " . JIRA_URL ."/browse/{$result->key}\n";
 }

 ?>
```

the fields with xxxx are replaced for security reason.
i want to know how i can correct this error.

Answer (score 2):

While I see this was asked nearly a year ago, I'll go ahead and answer:

The "not on the appropriate screen, or unknown" error occurs because the account you're using does not have permission to view those fields.

Log into your JIRA instance with the account credentials you are providing to the service, and try to create a ticket in the same queue (project) that you are using as the value of `$new_issue["fields"]["project"]["key"]`. **This is important, as different queues will have different permissions.** When the form comes up with the fields for creating an issue, you likely will not see the "summary" and "description" fields. The account you're using will need to be added to the Administrator group (there are other groups with differing permissions, such as Developer and Member).

Comment: Well i see those fields. And also i am the administrator of the jira - yet i receive the same error. Do you have any additional info about this?

Comment: We fixed this issue by adding the account that we were using (for accessing the API) to the 'Administrators' role under "Users and roles".   For us that was under "plugins/servlet/project-config/AC/roles"